# Error with custom module after compile

Tags: magento-2.1

**Error:**

**Fatal error:**

Method Magento\Ui\TemplateEngine\Xhtml\Result::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught TypeError: Argument 5 passed to Sparx\Drm\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection\Interceptor::__construct() must implement interface Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface, string given, called in /home/bargaink/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93 in /home/bargaink/public_html/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Wrapper/UiComponent.php on line 0

When i removed var/di error removed. But when i again run bin/magento setup:di:compile i got same error.

magento version 2.1.7

Here is the file:

```
<?php 
namespace Sparx\Drm\Model\ResourceModel\Grid;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
    /**
     * Define resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    // protected function _construct()
    // {
    //     $this->_init('Sparx\Drm\Model\Drm', 'Sparx\Drm\Model\ResourceModel\Drm');
    // }


    protected $_idFieldName = 'id';

    protected $_storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $connection, $resource);
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Sparx\Drm\Model\Drm','Sparx\Drm\Model\ResourceModel\Drm');
        $this->_map['fields']['entity_id'] = 'main_table.id';
    }

}
```

Is there something wrong with the coding?

Thanks

Comment: If parameters are not passed as expected order and proper then it is giving error while di:compile

Answer (score 2):

Replace __construct function with following code :

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
    \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager

) {
    parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $connection = null, $resource = null);
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- List item

Must need to check di file and virtual type name as '.../../../Grid/Collection'

> '..'
>             ..\..\Model\ResourceModel\..
>         
>       
>
>         
>             
>                 
>                  ..\Grid\Collection